# bulk add to NEW address book with powershell in O365

Tags: powershell, outlook, office365

I have a big list of client email addresses that need to be accessible to all internal employees. i have created a new address list to use using:

```
New-addresslist –name “TRH MP List”
New-GlobalAddressList –name “TRH MP List”
```

the list shows up in my address book in Outlook but says i can't edit it (even though i made myself an admin of it.)

I found this but it seems to only be able to add the main GLOBAL address list.

```
Import-Csv C:\ExternalContacts.csv|%{New-MailContact -Name $_.Name -DisplayName $_.Name -ExternalEmailAddress $_.ExternalEmailAddress -FirstName $_.FirstName -LastName $_.LastName}
```

I've been googling but the above is the only thing that ever turns up.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is the ability to hide the newly created external contacts from the Global Address List, but still have them be accessible as members of distribution groups.

If this is the case, here's the steps (referenced from https://community.office365.com/en-us/w/exchange/579)

**Hide a single external contact**

```html
Set-MailContact <external contact> -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $true
```

For example, to hide Franz Kohl from the shared address book:

```html
Set-MailContact “Franz Kohl” -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $true
```

**Hide all external contacts**

Run the following command to hide all external contacts from the shared address book:

```html
Get-Contact -ResultSize unlimited -Filter {(RecipientTypeDetails -eq 'MailContact')} | Set-MailContact -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $true
```

After you hide them, external contacts aren’t displayed in the shared address book, but you can still add them as members of a distribution group.

Comment: not quite. I DO need the addresses visible. i did finally realize what the filters are when creating the AddressList
    

    Set-GlobalAddressList -Identity “TRH MP List” -RecipientFilter "Company -eq 'Company Name'”
    Set-AddressList -Identity “TRH MP List” -RecipientFilter "Company -eq 'Company Name'”

however, its still not doing it properly. the list is empty.